# Why are all of the base immutable collections final or sealed in scala?

Tags: scala, language-design

I wrote a trait for sorting iterables in Scala, and it took almost as long to make a class that I could mix it in with as it took to write the trait.  Why was the design decision made to disallow users from writing things like:

```
new List[Int] with SuperAwesomeTrait[Int]?
```

Now if I want to do this, I need to do some weird hack like,

```
class StupidList extends LinearSeq {
  val inner = List()
  /* reimplement list methods by calling into inner */
}
```

and then

```
new StupidList[Int] with SuperAwesomeTrait[Int].
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because if I write

```
someList match {
  case Cons(head, tail) => whatever
  case Nil => somethingElse
}
```

I don't want my logic broken by a new, unexpected subclass.

I suspect you're trying to solve a problem using subclassing that would be better solved with implicits.

Comment: However the same practice would result in me pitching the immutable out of the stdlib by almost infinite force. Cons, however returns a new list so you're not broken.

Comment: Why is this a problem for `List` more than for any other class?

Comment: @Joshua, I have no idea what you're talking about.  I'm using pattern matching to deconstruct something.  I'm not creating anything.

Comment: @LuigiPlinge, it's a problem for any closed algebra (e.g. Option).

Comment: I have a general pattern where I extend lists to add various helper methods.

Comment: I don't see how a "new, unexpected subclass" would break pattern matching; can you elaborate or give a hypothetical example that would break it?

Comment: @DanBurton, let's say I have a new list subclass that I have someList refer to that isn't Cons or Nil.  James' code would then throw a MatchError.  Furthermore, if it was a function defined as:
    {
      case Cons(head, tail)=>0
      case Nil => 1
    }
then it would have to be a PartialFunction if we added in StupidList which inherits from List.